# Adding Recipients to Appointment VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

the code below creates a recurring Outlook appointment and another Outlook appointment through Excel and VBA. i'm trying to send the appointment to a different inbox, but i keep getting the "Run-time Error 287: Application-defined or object-defined error" at the line "OutlookAppt.Recipients.Add ("XXXXXX@company-company.com")". the code works, except when i add this line, so i'm wondering why.

please let me know if you have any ideas as to how to fix this.

thank you a bunch in advance!

```
Sub CompleteReminders()
    Dim rows
    Dim sDate As Date, newFU As Date, newDate As Date, iDate As Date, generalDate As Date
    Dim iValue As Integer
    Dim iteration As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim myNamespace As Object
    Dim objfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim OutlookAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim OutlookAppt2 As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim myRecurrPatt As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9
    Const olAppointment = 26
    Dim n As Integer
  

    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If ErrL <> 0 Then
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        End If

    Set myNamespace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objfolder = myNamespace.PickFolder 'Sets folder where appt will be created
  
    Set xRg = Range("B6:D6")
    
                Set OutlookAppt = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
                OutlookAppt.Duration = 5
                Set myRecurrPatt = OutlookAppt.GetRecurrencePattern
                With myRecurrPatt
                .PatternStartDate = Range("C1").Value
                .RecurrenceType = olRecursMonthNth
                .Interval = Range("C3").Value
                .PatternEndDate = dateEnd
                .StartTime = #5:00:00 PM#
                .EndTime = #5:05:00 PM#
                End With
                OutlookAppt.Subject = xRg.Cells(1, 1).Value
        
                If xRg.Cells(1, 2).Value > 0 Then
                    OutlookAppt.ReminderSet = True
                    OutlookAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = xRg.Cells(4, 6).Value
                Else
                    OutlookAppt.ReminderSet = False
                End If
                OutlookAppt.Body = xRg.Cells(1, 3).Value
                
                OutlookAppt.BusyStatus = olFree
                OutlookAppt.Recipients.Add ("XXXXXX@company-company.com")
                OutlookAppt.Save
                
                Set OutlookAppt = objfolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't this be `OutlookAppt.To = "Email address"`?

Comment: @Cyril just tried - it gives me Run-time error '438' : Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: My apologies; that's for sending emails, not generating meetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is running unattended, make sure the security prompt is not getting in the way. Make sure antivirus app and its definitions are up-to-date.

Also try to replace the problematic line line with

```
OutlookAppt.RequiredAttendees = "XXXXXX@company-company.com"
```

For the `RequiredAttendees` property, only reading is blocked, but not setting.

Comment: @uhsahar - If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In some really quick testing, I was able to get the line to work by setting the object (recipients are objects):

```
Dim requiredRecipient as Outlook.Recipient
Set requiredRecipient = OutlookAppt.Recipients.Add ("XXXXXX@company-company.com")
requiredRecipient.Type = olRequired
```

Docs for reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients

Comment: aaaa that's so odd mine still isn't working. is there a specific spot i'm meant to put this code or right before the OutlookAppt.Save should work?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [AppointmentItem.RequiredAttendees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.requiredattendees) property instead. Also you may find the [AppointmentItem.OptionalAttendees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.optionalattendees?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm888)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property helpful which returns or sets a string representing the display string of optional attendees names for the appointment. This is a semicolon-delimited string of required attendee names for the meeting appointment.

In case of using the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.recipients) property for meetings you need to use the [OlMeetingRecipientType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmeetingrecipienttype) enumeration.

```
OutlookAppt.Recipients.Add "XXXXXX@company-company.com"
```

Comment: not familiar with this,, from what i'm reading, it would display the names of the people invited to the appointment. however, i'm more trying to add someone using an email. i'll check out the recipient type link though, thank you!

Comment: The attendee list should be set by using the `Recipients` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `()` when calling `Recipients.Add`:

```
OutlookAppt.Recipients.Add "XXXXXX@company-company.com"
```

or change it to

```
set Recip = OutlookAppt.Recipients.Add ("XXXXXX@company-company.com")
```

`()` in VB are only used when calling a function, but not a sub.

Comment: tried both - not working. does the placement of the line in the block of code matter at all ?